# SQL Inequality in duplicates

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

I found a question in an exam paper which consists of a table Forest having these attributes

```
Name - type : C(10)
Size - type : I
Location - type : C(10)
Company - type : C(10)
```

Basically the question asks to find all forests found in the same location with the same company and create this table by that information

Smaller_Forest Larger_Forest CompanyName

I am stuck when I am meant to sort the duplicates by smaller or larger in terms of SQL.

Am I meant to do a CROSS JOIN and eliminate forests with the same size or something like that? And if so, how am I to place the larger and smaller forest in the same record (maybe by the company name value ? )

To filter out the duplicates I did this:

```
Select * INTO ForestSameLocationCompany 
GROUP BY Location, Company 
HAVING (count(distinct Location)>1) AND (count(distinct Company)>1)
```

So this is meant to give me a table with all the duplicate forests by location and company. All is left is to sort them into the above mentioned table which is where I am stuck.

Any help on this matter is much appreciated.

Comment: Consider using the `size` column and adding an `ORDER BY` clause somewhere.

Comment: I don't see how the expected result makes any sense given the input. Are there only ever two forests per company? Or are those columns supposed to be named "smallest" and "largest"?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `SELECT * INTO ...` is non-standard SQL.

Comment: Right now no dbms since my pc is BSODing me so its being formatted.. im doing it by pen and paper until the OS finishes and typing from my old laptop so i expect that i did a syntax error. 

Yes im guessing he is asking me to assume there are at most 2 forests per company and location duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is suspect, because it assumes that there are only two forests when there are duplicates.  I would start by doing:

```
select cnt, count(*)
from (select company, location, count(*) as cnt
      from Forest
      group by company, location
     ) cl
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

This tells you the distribution of the number of companies per forest.

Then, if you only have two forests per company/location, there are several ways to get the name of the smallest and largest on one line.  One problem, of course, is that the two forests could have the same size -- and that could be troubling for the approaches.  Here is an attempt:

```
select company, location,
       min(case when size = minsize then name end) as minForest,
       max(case when size = maxsize then name end) as maxForest
from Forest f join
     (select company, location, min(size) as minsize, max(size) as maxsize
      from forest
      group by company, location
      having count(*) > 1
     ) cl
     on f.company = cl.company and f.location = cl.location
group by company, location;
```

By using both `min()` and `max()` in the `select` clause, the query will return both names when the sizes are the same.

As an additional comment, I find such an exercise to be less useful than it should be.  There are plenty of examples of real-world data where you have to deal with duplicates.  By not mentioning issues such as the number of possible solution and what to do when the forests are the same size, the exercise is a bit misleading as a real-world example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! Yes it is quite misleading .. that was the general story with this teacher throughout the entire semester.